# How to replace a text with coloured text using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I am having this text in text area.

```
{color:#c91d1d}Hello{color}
```

when it is submitted, i want the text between {} tags to be shown in color specified inside {} tag with color:

how can i do so in javascript

Comment: why do you need the `{} ..{}` syntax? Why not generate the html when selecting color?

Comment: What text editor are you using? Maybe consider switching to one that generates html instead.

Comment: that is my requirement to use {color:somecolor}text{color} and I am using markdown editor.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript built in function to extract color code

```
 var colorValue = str.substring(7, 7);
```

it extract 7 characters from 7th position.

now change the color using:

```
document.getElementById("myH2").style.color = colorValue;
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Thank you Rahul, but I am looking for replacing {color:red}text{color} this content with text in red. and the selected text in the textarea has to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like

```js
$('#input').on('input', function() {
  $('#result').html(this.value.replace(/\{color:(.*?)\}(.*?)((\{color\})|$)/g, '<span style="color:$1">$2</span>'));
}).triggerHandler('input');
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input">{color:#c91d1d}Hello{color} - {color:green}hi{color}</textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you Arun ji, suppose,if I add another {color:green}hi{color} to that div then, what will be the result.

Comment: please help me. your answer is very closed to me. @Arun P Johny

Comment: not working @Arun. I am getting the result like this {color:#c91d1d}Hello

Comment: what is the input text tried... the text I have in the div seems to be working

Comment: I have given like this {color:#c91d1d}Hello{color}... and o/p will be {color:#c91d1d}Hello

Comment: its just replacing {color} with blank but {color:#c91d1d}Hello coming as it is @Arun

Answer (score 0):

Arun is right, and if you just need to get "Hello" from "{color:#c91d1d}Hello{color}" string you can do it like this

```js
var justtext="{color:#c91d1d}Hello{color}".match(/\{.*\}(.*)\{.*\}/)[1];
```

For full replacement of text in textarea here's the code. Suppose textarea has id attribute "textarea1", change it with your id.

```js
var textwithcolor =$("#textarea1").text();
var justtext=textwithcolor.match(/\{.*\}(.*)\{.*\}/)[1];
$("#textarea1").text(justtext);
```

Comment: Hi vuk, I tried as Arun suggestion. but not able replace correctly. please help me

Answer (score 0):

this is how it can be done
No need to use regular expressions.

try this

```js
var str = $('#t').text();
var res = str.substring(7, 14);
newstr = str;
while (newstr.indexOf("{color}") > -1) {
  newstr = newstr.replace("{color}", "</div>");
}
while (newstr.indexOf("{color:") > -1) {
  newstr = newstr.replace("{color:", "<div style='color:");
  newstr = newstr.replace("}", "'>");
}

document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = newstr;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="t">{color:#c91d1d}Hello{color}
   {color:red}How{color} {color:yellow}are{color} {color:green}you{color}
</div>
```

Comment: hi, you can not give the sub string as 7-14. I can add any no of {color} tags. suppose if I add two or more {color:red}red{color}{color:red}green{color}, then?, and your hard coding the sub string, we have to use regex as suggested by Arun

Comment: i have edited my answer, now it behaves exactly as you want :)

Comment: I have given the concept, you can use this to achieve whatever you want :)

Comment: @Joy is there still any problem?